# How to access arcgis cache directly using leaflet like openlayers?

Tags: leaflet

I want to access arcgis server cache dircetly by only using leaflet,I wrote some code,but it work badly,could you anyone give me any hints?
my code:
getTileUrl: function (tilePoint) {

```
    var zoom = this._map.getZoom();

    var map = this._map;
    var crs = map.options.crs;

    var tileSize = this.options.tileSize;

    var nwPoint = tilePoint.multiplyBy(tileSize);
    var sePoint = nwPoint.add(new L.Point(tileSize, tileSize));
    var midX = (nwPoint.x + sePoint.x) / 2;
    var midY = (nwPoint.y + sePoint.y) / 2;
    var p = new L.Point(midX, midY);


    var tilep = crs.project(map.unproject(p, zoom));

    var z = zoom, x = tilep.x, y = tilep.y, url;

    url = this._url;
    var z1;
    if (z < 10)
    {
        z1 = 'L0' + z + '/';
    }
    else {
        z1 = 'L' + z + '/';
    }

    var row = Math.floor(Math.abs((this.options.tileOrigin.y - y) / (this.options.tileSize * this.options.res[z])));
    //console.info(row);
    var col = Math.floor(Math.abs((x - this.options.tileOrigin.x) / (this.options.tileSize * this.options.res[z])));
    //console.info(col);
    url = this._url + z1 + 'R' + this.zeroPad(row, 8, 16) + '/C' + this.zeroPad(col,8,16) + '.' + this.options.format;  
    return url;
}
```

It's inherited from TileLayer,and I just change this function.

Comment: it would be helpful if we could see your code

Comment: why dont u use L.AgsDynamicLayer or  L.TileLayer in leaflet?

Comment: @Aragon,I dont want to use ArcGIS server,but the data source is generated by arcgis server.